# Azure Functions keep returning 'The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, tls1.2, client-certificates

I have an Azure Functions that keep returning me "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized". The certificate (pfx format) has been uploaded to Azure as a private key certificate - look at the picture below - and has the status healthy and I can read the 3 certificates in them.

[image]

I have also set the appSettings WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE=1 and WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES=thumbprints but with no luck. Here are my application settings for the function app.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using when handling the certificate. I'm following the official documentation by Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-windows-apps

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

string certThumbprint = "certThumbprint";
bool validOnly = false;

using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
  certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

  X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                              X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                              // Replace below with your certificate's thumbprint
                              certThumbprint,
                              validOnly);
  // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
  X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();

  if (cert is null)
      throw new Exception($"Certificate with thumbprint {certThumbprint} was not found");

  // Use certificate
  Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName); 
}
```

Comment: Could you please restart your function app after changing the property `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` to `1` in application settings.

Comment: @HuryShen thank you for helping out. I've already tried that with no luck.

Comment: The problem was this line -> X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();. I changed it to  if (certCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    return certCollection[0];
                } and then it worked

Comment: You can post an answer below for other communities reference.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize the comments provided by author for other communities reference:

The problem was caused by the line of code: `X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();`

Changed the line of code to: `if (certCollection.Count > 0) { return certCollection[0]; }`, then it works.